# Using a class constructor to handle images tkinter

Tags: python, class, oop, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Hi i'm trying to create a class constructor to handle images in tkinter, since i'll be using many images in my code so I need a way to use images without using so much line of code.

I keep getting the error:

```
   return _modes[mode]
KeyError: 'picture.png'
```

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
from random import randint

from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry('700x700')

class PhotoHandler:
    def __init__(self,imagepath):
        self.imagepath = imagepath
        self.image = Image.open(self.imagepath)
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.imagepath)

    def returnn(self):
        return self.image

search = PhotoHandler('picture.png').returnn()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You passed a string to the tkinter image. It expects a PIL image or mode. Since you passed a string, it thinks you're using an invalid mode. Pass the image instead:

```
class PhotoHandler:
    def __init__(self,imagepath):
        self.imagepath = imagepath
        self.image = Image.open(self.imagepath)
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)

    def returnn(self):
        return self.image

search = PhotoHandler('picture.png').returnn()

# add label for background image
background_label = tkinter.Label(root, image=search)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Here's the documentation:
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/reference/ImageTk.html

Comment: silly mistake by me didn't see that, thank you very much

Comment: I added the label already for the picture, but sometimes the image doesn't show, something to do with garbage collector